# Variable image sizes in transfer learning (inception_resnet_v2)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, keras-layer, tensorflow-hub

I am running an image feature extraction task with Tensorflow Hub and a feature vector from Inception-Resnet trained on Imagenet (no classification head). From the docs, it is possible to use different image sizes as input. Wondering if would be correct to initialize the feature extractor just once (without specifying input_shape) and then feeding it with different image sizes?
For instance, when running it on a single image (with / without input_shape initialization) the output feature vector is the same:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
!pip install -q -U tf-hub-nightly --user
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
img=Image.open('image.png') # RGB image, (148, 299, 3)
img = np.array(img)/255.0

# extract features after specifying image_shape
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_resnet_v2/feature_vector/4"
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,input_shape=img.shape)
feature_img_shape = feature_extractor_layer(img[np.newaxis, ...])

# extract features without specifying image_shape
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_resnet_v2/feature_vector/4"
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url)
feature_img_noshape = feature_extractor_layer(img[np.newaxis, ...])

# Check if the feature vectors are the same
np.array_equal(feature_img_shape.numpy(),feature_img_noshape.numpy())
True
```

Comment: Hi, tried reproducing your code and it is resulting in Value Error. Please find the Github Gist in the link, https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/9615c9a844cfc15d156a1cf9bf8c1d2c/58867998.ipynb. Please help us in reproducing the error so that we can try to help you. Thanks!